# resets error during normal import on python django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have an import error. I have a *User* model on *models.py*, I import it on *serializers.py*. Previously, everything worked as it should, I even worked with other files and suddenly an error appears on *serializers.py*. And sorry for my English writing via google translate.

> models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
phone_number = models.CharField('телефон номер', max_length=20, unique=True,db_index=True)
avatar = models.ImageField('Аватар', blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_timestamp_path, default='images/user.png')
nickname = models.CharField('Никнейм', max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
register_date = models.DateField('Дата регистрация', auto_now_add=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField('Активен', default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField('Суперпользователь', default=False)
region = models.ForeignKey(Region, verbose_name="", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.nickname = 'User' + str(self.id)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_full_name(self):
    return self.phone_number

def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.phone_number

def __str__(self):
    return self.phone_number

USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = UserManager()

class Meta:
    verbose_name= 'User'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

> serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User
```

> error

```
File "/home/c2dent/afmoon/backend/afmoon/main/models.py", line 7, in <module>
from .utilities import get_timestamp_path
File "/home/c2dent/afmoon/backend/afmoon/main/utilities.py", line 8, in <module>
from .serializers import HouseSerializer, LandSerialzier, VacancySerializer, ResumeSerializer, SecondSerializer, PersonalsClothesSerializer, PersonalsShoesSerializeres, CommonProductDetail, AvtomobilSerialzier, ApartmentSerializer


File "/home/c2dent/afmoon/backend/afmoon/main/serializers.py", line 2, in <module>
from .models import User, BaseProduct, Avtomobil, Apartment, House, Land, Vacancy, Resume, Second, Personals_clothes, Personals_shoes
ImportError: cannot import name 'User
```

Comment: Are all these files in the same folder? Or are they in different folders?

Comment: In one folder, this is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular import. The models file imports utilities, which imports serializers, which in turn imports models.

Restructure the files to import this. Does utilities really need to import serializers?